# How do I index polymorphic (STI) models in Rails 5 with Thinking Sphinx without a circular dependency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm integrating a simple indexed search for a `rails 5.1.4` application, using `Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6)` and `thinking_sphinx v 4.0.0`

**Expected behavior:**

When I submit a new search, I expect to see either an empty array `[]` or a set of search results.

**Actual behavior:**

When I submit a new search with empty parameters *from the view layer* and try to access the ThinkingSphinx::Search object via a `binding.pry` in the controller action, rails throws a `ActionView::Template::Error (Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant StudentLesson)`

```
[1] pry(main)> ThinkingSphinx.search ''
=> [#<ThinkingSphinx::Search:0x2b0925399e10>
[2] pry(main)> _.inspect
RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant StudentLesson
from /home/kf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3@crm/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in `load_missing_constant'
[3] pry(main)>
```

**Code snippets:**

```rb
class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  LESSON_TYPES = {
    'StudentLesson': StudentLesson,
    'ProfessionalLesson': ProfessionalLesson
  }.freeze
end

class StudentLesson < Lesson
  after_save ThinkingSphinx::RealTime.callback_for(:student_lesson)
end

class ProfessionalLesson < Lesson
  after_save ThinkingSphinx::RealTime.callback_for(:professional_lesson)
end
```

```rb
# app/indices/student_lesson_index.rb
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :student_lesson, with: :real_time do
  indexes name, sortable: true
end

# app/indices/professional_lesson_index.rb
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :professional_lesson, with: :real_time do
  indexes name, sortable: true
end
```

```rb
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @results = []
  end

  def create
    @results = ThinkingSphinx.search(params[:search])
    render :index
  end
end
```

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="header-navbar">
   <%= render 'layouts/nav_links' %>
   <%= form_for searches_path do %>
     <%= search_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
     <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil, method: :get %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

Here's the `dev.sphinx.conf`

```
indexer
{
}

searchd
{
  listen = 127.0.0.1:9306:mysql41
  log = /home/myapp/log/development.searchd.log
  query_log = /home/myapp/log/development.searchd.query.log
  pid_file = /home/myapp/log/development.sphinx.pid
  workers = threads
  binlog_path = /home/myapp/tmp/binlog/development
}

index game_core
{
  type = rt
  path = /home/myapp/db/sphinx/development/game_core
  docinfo = extern
  rt_field = sphinx_internal_class_name
  rt_field = name
  rt_field = summary
  rt_attr_uint = sphinx_deleted
  rt_attr_bigint = sphinx_internal_id
  rt_attr_timestamp = created_at
  rt_attr_timestamp = updated_at
  rt_attr_string = sphinx_internal_class
  rt_attr_string = name_sort
}

index lesson_core
{
  type = rt
  path = /home/myapp/db/sphinx/development/lesson_core
  docinfo = extern
  rt_field = sphinx_internal_class_name
  rt_field = name
  rt_field = purpose
  rt_field = meta
  rt_field = supplies
  rt_field = activity
  rt_attr_uint = sphinx_deleted
  rt_attr_bigint = sphinx_internal_id
  rt_attr_timestamp = created_at
  rt_attr_timestamp = updated_at
  rt_attr_string = sphinx_internal_class
  rt_attr_string = name_sort
}

index protocol_core
{
  type = rt
  path = /home/myapp/db/sphinx/development/protocol_core
  docinfo = extern
  rt_field = sphinx_internal_class_name
  rt_field = name
  rt_field = description
  rt_attr_uint = sphinx_deleted
  rt_attr_bigint = sphinx_internal_id
  rt_attr_timestamp = created_at
  rt_attr_timestamp = updated_at
  rt_attr_string = sphinx_internal_class
  rt_attr_string = name_sort
}

index resource_page_core
{
  type = rt
  path = /home/myapp/db/sphinx/development/resource_page_core
  docinfo = extern
  rt_field = sphinx_internal_class_name
  rt_field = header
  rt_field = content
  rt_attr_uint = sphinx_deleted
  rt_attr_bigint = sphinx_internal_id
  rt_attr_timestamp = created_at
  rt_attr_timestamp = updated_at
  rt_attr_string = sphinx_internal_class
  rt_attr_string = header_sort
}

index game
{
  type = distributed
  local = game_core
}

index lesson
{
  type = distributed
  local = lesson_core
}

index protocol
{
  type = distributed
  local = protocol_core
}

index resource_page
{
  type = distributed
  local = resource_page_core
}
```

Comment: Sup Keifer! How you been?!  When you search with params does it work? Any errors?

Comment: Searching in the console with empty params returns a results set successfully, but when searching from the view and checking the results in a `binding.pry` I am met with `[#<ThinkingSphinx::Search:0x3fd34aba5448>` which when inspecting that `Search` object I see the circular dependency error - something might be wrong with my models but everything else is working as expected outside of ThinkingSphinx

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is not directly related to Thinking Sphinx - it just errors because it can't load the search results due to the circular dependency in your models - particularly, the `LESSON_TYPES` constant:

- Thinking Sphinx makes a search call, and in its result set it has at least one `StudentLesson` instance, so it needs to load that model.
- Loading `StudentLesson` finds its dependency (as a subclass) on `Lesson`.
- Loading `Lesson` finds its dependency (as references to constants) on both `StudentLesson` and `ProfessionalLesson`.
- So, `StudentLesson` is attempted to be loaded again, and hence the endless loop of dependencies.

(FWIW I just confirmed this behaviour in a test Rails app using the model code you've provided, without TS being involved: all I needed to run in a console was `StudentLesson.first`.)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 classes which both inherit a constant definition, this looks problematic.

Try moving this constant definition to an initializer:

```
LESSON_TYPES = {
    'StudentLesson': StudentLesson,
    'ProfessionalLesson': ProfessionalLesson
  }.freeze
```

Comment: Hey Lance! Nice to hear from you - I've updated the question with the development configuration. This error happens when triggering from the view but not when directly calling `ThinkingSphinx.search(nil)` in the rails console. Also sending `ThinkingSphinx.search('')` or `ThinkingSphinx.search({})` return the same set when in the the console. 

However, when inspecting `@results` from a `binding.pry` in the controller action, the results look like `[#<ThinkingSphinx::Search:0x3fd34aba5448>`, which is a broken array, and inspecting the `.first` element in that array gives the circular error

Comment: Thinking Sphinx is fine with nil being passed through - it just gets treated as an empty string :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually found in the comment thread for a still open issue with [spring](https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/340), which is resolved by initializing `require_dependency 'lesson'` -> which I actually already had in an initializer but moving it to a `Rails.application.config.to_prepare` block solved the reloading issues and therein the Sphinx-related symptoms.

Comment: Nice one! Maybe you wanna post the code setup which solved the issue!